# How do I set a lower bound to the solution's norm in a quadratic program?

Tags: optimization, convex-optimization, quadratic-programming, regularization

I know that LASSO-regularization can be used to scale into an $L_1$ upper bound for a solution. But what if I want the norm to be within a specific range $[a,b]$? ie. I also want to set a lower bound?

In other words: I am looking for an efficient method to solve a QP problem with a constraint on the norm of the solution ($a\leq\|x\|\leq b$), not on the individual components of the solution ($AX\leq b$).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It cannot be done in a convex optimization or a standard quadratic programming framework. Lower bounds on the norm are *non-convex*. No efficient method exists that will reliably obtain the global solution to such a problem.

On the [CVX Forum](http://ask.cvxr.com), a user asked a similar question [here](http://ask.cvxr.com/answers/35/edit/). Professor Stephen Boyd offered up an answer that is not specific to CVX, but can be used in any convex optimization setting. I will quote it here in full just in case the link goes dead some day.

> mcg's answer is correct; the problem is not convex, and cannot be
>   expressed in DCP format.   more specifically, a constraint like
>   $\|Aw\|_2 \leq P$ (with $A$ a constant matrix and $w$ a variable) is
>   OK (convex, and DCP), but the converse constraint, $\|Aw\|_2 \geq P$,
>   is not convex, and (therefore) not DCP.
>
> i'd like to add that there are heuristic methods for "handling" such
>   problems, using the so-called convex-concave procedure (see EE364b,
>   lecture on sequential convex programming).   this is a heuristic
>   method, that uses convex optimization as a subroutine, to "solve"
>   problems like this one.  heuristic means the method can fail; the $w$
>   found need not be the global solution.  but such methods can work well
>   in practice.
>
> for a reverse norm inequality like this, the method works as follows. 
>   we replace $\|Aw\|_2 \geq P$ with the convex (and DCP) constraint
>   $q^T(Aw) \geq P$, where $q=(Aw^\mathrm{prev})/\|Aw^\mathrm{prev}\|_2$,
>   where $w^\mathrm{prev}$ is the value of $w$ at the last iteration. 
>   solving the resulting convex problem gives us the new value of $w$. 
>   (you must start with a nonzero value of $w$.  in fact, you might start
>   the convex-concave procedure with several different values of $w$; you
>   could well get different final results.)
>
> our experience is that this works quite well in practice.  but
>   remember that this method does not find the global solution.

There is one other solution I can think of. You have not specified which norm you are considering. But if you would consider the $\ell_\infty$ norm $\|x\|_\infty=\max_i|x_i|$, then you can handle this constraint in a mixed-integer quadratic programming (MIQP) system. To see why, consider the following constraint:
$$2ay_i+(a-b)z_i-a\leq x_i \leq a+(b-a)y_i-2az_i, \quad y_i,z_i\in\{0,1\},~y_i+z_i\leq 1$$
This constraint works as follows:

- if $y_i=z_i=0$, then $-a\leq x_i \leq a$; that is, $|x_i|\leq a$.
- if $y_i=1$, $z_i=0$, then $a\leq x_i\leq b$.
- if $y_i=0$, $z_i=1$, then $-b\leq x_i\leq -a$; that is, $a\leq -x_i\leq b$.
- $y_i=z_i=1$ is forbidden by the $y_i+z_i\leq 1$ constraint.

If we repeat these constraints for all $i=1,2,\dots, n$, then we ensure that $\|x\|_\infty\leq b$. And if we require that at least *one* $y_i,z_i$ is nonzero, then we are ensuring that $\|x\|_\infty\geq a$. Thus this system of constraints will ensure $a\leq\|x\|_\infty\leq b$:
\begin{array}{cc}
2ay+(a-b)z-a\leq x \leq a+(b-a)y-2az \\
y_i,z_i\in\{0,1\},~y_i+z_i\leq 1,~i=1,2,\dots, n \\
\sum_i y_i + z_i \geq 1
\end{array}
This is $3n+1$ inequalities, $n$ original variables, and $2n$ new binary variables. There are no theoretical guarantees of tractability, but in practice you can probably handle a reasonably large $n$.